# How to attach batch/pre-install command line to Advanced Installer msi?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I'm using Advanced Installer to bundle a Visual Studio project into an msi file, but I also have several drivers to install before the whole installation takes off, including several Microsoft Visual C++ runtimes. Do I need to build an exe instead? Do the driver files need bundled in, as well, or do I need to leave those outside the msi file? Do I need to write a batch file, or does Advanced Installer have a handy tool for that?

I looked through a couple different installer helpers before settling on Advanced Installer, so that's not the question. I was briefly looking at Visual Studio Publish mode, but that looked like a web release thing--I'm not sure, tho, so if you know anything about that, please add that. I'm fairly new to any kind of installer helpers. I'm looking for quick and easy; I know that's hard to come by.

In the end, I'd really prefer this to end up being one big file to run--this is going on target machines running x64 Windows 10, and it would be ideal to only have to move one file around. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate setup (e.g. MSI) for your driver files and then create a bundle setup that will embed all of your setup packages: the drivers setup, the setup of your app files, the C++ runtime setup, and so on.

They even have a tutorial on their web site about how to bundle multiple setups into a unified one: [Creating Suite Installations](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html)